# PettingZoo multi-agent parallel environments: Human against the trained agent

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, pettingzoo

Is there a way to let humans play against agents (trained using self-play) in PettingZoo environments, similar to how the game would be played using the GUI?

For turn-based classical games (like rock-paper-scissors, tic-tac-toe, chess, etc), one can still make it work by mapping specific keys to the actions of the human agent. But how can this be achieved for real-time parallel games, say Atari Pong?

I tried using the idea mentioned above, but waiting for the user's input resulted in a laggy game experience.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.